# Какая сложность у обращения к элементу списка в Python?

Tags: python, list, сложность, индексация

Допустим, есть список:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Я хочу обратиться к списку:

```
print(numbers[4])
```

Какая сложность у обращения к n-ому элементу списка numbers? O(n) или O(1)

Comment: О(1). Это же не связный список.